# why does typescript assume array element lookup won't be undefined?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am surprised that this bit of typescript doesn't result in a type error (also available in the [typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rHgOwgFwCcBXYPeAgCgIFMwATHEAT2gA8AuabIgWwCNqBADTQa9Riyadu-QQEoUAX1TLUWXHjYB5AGawAlgXwIkAXmgUwBApwCC1sEwA8JgHxzpvAQWinXKdFFqPCICbGgrAgBtAAYAXQA6VhVUNRx8IIgiEE1zVl0DIzwTCii4hQB6CugAd30QEGhBAnIgA)):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(readonly x: number, readonly y: number) {}
}

const xOfFirstFoo = (arr: Array<Foo>): number => {
  return arr[0].x
}

const result = xOfFirstFoo([]);
// The above line results in:
// [ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
// [ERR]: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

Naively, I would have expected the typer to know that `arr[0]` (or, more generally, any `arr[i]`) could be a `Foo` or `undefined`, and so it can't be guaranteed that a `.x` property is available.

What's going on here?

Comment: Arrays are basically `{ [index: number]: T }`; *every* index is assumed to be defined, they don't have any length information (that's a *value*, not a type). You could use a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) if you expect exactly one thing.

Comment: You are looking for [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-rc/#no-unchecked-indexed-access). But this feature will be released with TS 4.1

Comment: @Shinigami did not know nothing about this flag. Thanks man!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why in TypeScript an array element accessed by index doesn't have "undefined" in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116910/why-in-typescript-an-array-element-accessed-by-index-doesnt-have-undefined-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments from @jonrsharpe and @shinigami helped me understand this! Paraphrasing:

1. Arrays are basically `{ [index: number]: T }`, where every value of `index` is assumed to have a defined `T` value. One can use a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) if a specific length is expected.
2. But with the flag [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-rc/#no-unchecked-indexed-access) (to be included in  TypeScript 4.1), the behavior will match my original expectation.  In particular:

> Under this new mode, every property access (like foo.bar) or indexed access (like foo["bar"]) is considered potentially undefined.