# typescript incorrectly missing a possible undefined in indexed records

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have defined a index-based `type X`. If I now use a non-exisiting key, then typescript down not infer the result type `ValueType | undefined` correctly.

How to fix this?

```
type ValueType = {
    foobar:string;
}  
type X = {
  indexbased: { [id: string]: ValueType}
}

const x : X = {indexbased: {}}

const id :string = "not-existing";

const indexvalue = x.indexbased[id];
// typescript infers const indexvalue: ValueType

console.log(indexvalue.foobar);
// Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foobar')
```

--

Update

If i use `type X = { indexbased: { [id: string]: ValueType|undefined} }`, then I will have to check every entry when looping over them:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(x.indexbased)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value.foobar}`);
}
```

This is a duplicate of [Why in TypeScript an array element accessed by index doesn't have "undefined" in its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116910/why-in-typescript-an-array-element-accessed-by-index-doesnt-have-undefined-in)

Comment: Does `{ [K in string]?: ValueType}` work for you?

Comment: @wonderflame No, it runs into various errors when using the `?` as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the typescript compiler options to be more pedantic when it comes to indexed access solves the issue:

```
{
"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
}
```